# I/O redirection and pipes in custom shell

Tags: c

I have to write my own shell in C and have already implemented 90% of the requirements (fg, bg, jobs, etc.). However, I have two more requirements that I'm stuck on. My shell must support I/O redirection and pipes. For example:

```
myprog < input.txt | myprog2 > output.txt
```

Any hints/ideas that anyone can provide to go about coding support for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) and [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted/needed to write my own shell in C. Part of an OS course. It might be slightly cheating but perhaps you can get some hints looking at the [BASH shell source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz)

There's a file called redir.c Maybe you could get some ideas from that and implement a simple version of pipes and redirect. For the example you have above, you would also need to cater for order of precedence, etc...

ALL THE BEST!!! :)